# DISTINCT COUNT overall after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have this data:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
PersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
PersonName varchar(10),
Year int
);

INSERT INTO Person (PersonID, PersonName, Year)
VALUES (1, 'Ben', 2015),
(2, 'Sam', 2016),
(3,'Ben', 2016),
(4,'Fred', 2017),
(5,'Alex', 2016),
(6,'Ben', 2017);
```

Now, i am trying to return a overall distinct count. e.g. The total of unique names over the whole data.

Say for example people are re-registered on the system each year.
How would i answer a question such as i need a count of how many people we have on the system from the beginning of time? keeping in mind that the 2 entries for Ben is the same person re-registered over a couple of years so this would only count as 1.

my initial approach would be this

```
SELECT  min(Year), COUNT(DISTINCT PersonName) FROM
Person
GROUP BY Year
```

Result

```
2015    1
2016    3
2017    2
```

However i know this isnt right because it groups by year and i am looking for a total of 4 as opposed to 6. Am i just missing something really simple?

sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/899cc8/2

Comment: Is `select count(distinct personname) from person` what you need?

Comment: there are the same person names counted for different years, therefore, the sum is not equal to 4. In other words, ben is counted in each year so it is not equal to `select count(distinct personname) from person`

Comment: Agree with @Psidom. You don't emphasize that you want to break it out by year. So remove the `Min(Year)` and you will get `4` as the result.

Comment: @WEI_DBA i dont know - see fiddle

Comment: I added an answer. You have the Year in your select and are grouping by the Year as well, so Ben will be counted multiple times since he registered in different years.

Comment: My question is since 2016 lists Ben, and Ben existed in 2015; should 2016 in your results only show 2? and 1 in 2017 since Ben was counted in 2015  Like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/899cc8/45/0

Comment: What expected results are desired?  the count of each persons distinct name by year 3 records {2015:1,2016:2,2017:1}?  or just the count of 4? or should it be {2015:0,2016:2,2017:2} in which case ben is assigned in 2017 not 2015; nor 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/899cc8/49/0)

It appears you're after a count by year; but exclude the count of names already having occured in prior years.

So we use a row_number to identify the earliest entry of each personName by year, and then only count the 1st rows of each personName by year.

```
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT [Year]
       , PersonName
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonName ORDER BY [Year] Asc) RN
  FROM Person)
SELECT Count(*), [Year]
FROM cte 
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY [Year]
ORDER BY [Year]
```

Giving us:

```
+------+---------------+
| Year | UniqPersonCnt |
+------+---------------+
| 2015 |             1 |
| 2016 |             2 |
| 2017 |             1 |
+------+---------------+
```

The reason your example didn't work was because the count of names is grouped by year so the distinct only applied to each year, when you wanted it applied to the whole set.

It's also why I asked in comment about when Ben needed to be counted.  In the earliest year? latest year?  what did you expect to see each year?

Comment: Nice! I have the same approach in mind, but using a derived table instead of cte

Comment: Yep same idea roughly similar times ;P  and I daresay either is what the question is about.

Comment: @xQbert exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT personname) FROM person
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using the `row_number()` function and a derived table. With this, it shows in the format year | count:

```
select year
      ,count(rn) as count_of_unique_name_by_year
from
(SELECT  Year
        ,row_number() over (partition by personname order by year) rn
FROM Person) t
where t.rn = 1
group by year
```

Answer (score 0):

As Psidom says, this is all you need to return the result of 4.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT PersonName) 
FROM Person
```